# which rosserial to use?

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

based on this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/196204/unable-to-sync-with-device-arduino-uno/, I wonder which one should be installed and used:

1. ros-indigo-rosserial (and everything
   relates to it) or
2. the one from the rosserial
   repository, under
   indigo-devel branch

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203746/which-rosserial-to-use?/) by [whiterose](https://answers.ros.org/users/349/whiterose/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2015-02-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are using ROS Indigo, either one of the ones you mentioned should work fine.
I installed ros-indigo-rosserial via apt-get and it works flawlessly.

---

Originally posted by [Valts](https://answers.ros.org/users/7561/valts/) with karma: 41 on 2015-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1